# PyGTK application example

Tags: python, gtk, application-development, pygtk

I'm planing to write my first Ubuntu app. I'm new in Python and looking for good example, an open source app, just to pick the patterns and architecture.

Is there any good example? It would be nice if app is available in Ubuntu  Software center as well.

Also, I see that PyGTK is being phased out and replaced with PyGObject ( [Is PyGTK still relevant?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85056/is-pygtk-still-relevant) ). I wanted to use quickly, is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to give a good example application, because it might do completely different things than your app. So to name just anything: you could look at [jokosher](http://www.jokosher.org/), [exaile](http://www.exaile.org/), or the [ubuntu one client](https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client).

If you want to learn to python however, I would recommend something more tutorial/reference like. You might want to look into [diveintopython](http://www.diveintopython.net/).

As for pygtk and gobjects: pygtk is the way to go, if you want something that works and is documented (now). If you want to learn and develop slowly and have something ready in a year or two, you should definitley focus on gobjects. quickly, which is a good way to go is currently also using pygtk. For more on these topics, please visit the [ubuntu developer site.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)